# cache manifest uncache

Tags: caching, manifest

Now that I've successfully cached my web page, how do I uncache it after making a change?

My user can't dl the latest version, even after I've changed a comment in my cache.manifest file.

My server is an IIS server.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with caching is, well, stuff gets cached. Browsers won't, in general, try to download anything you've told them to cache until the cached items expire.

If you set everything to cache for a certain time span, the browser won't try to download any of the cached items until the end of it, which includes the cache.manifest file itself, by the sound of it.

Typically, you don't want to cache the content of the website, because then that makes it hard to change. Instead, you want to cache the various pieces, like images, css, and javascript, that the various pages of your site need. If you do this right, you can get a huge benefit for your users, and still have control over those resources, since you can always link to a different version of a particular resource in the content of the pages.

That said, if you *do* need to cache some portions of your pages, you can use server-side caching to reuse portions that are expensive to put together.

Comment: Thanks cdeszaq!  That was very thought out.  My client is requiring my html5 application to run while their browser is offline.